# pyodbc Timeout Error, Multiple Port Bindings

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, docker, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to connect to a SQL Server docker container. Here are some screen shots. The first one is the output of `docker ps -a`. The second one is a couple of lines from a python shell where I try to connect to to the SQL Server. Both are running on my local computer.

My questions are this: is it a problem for my container to have two different port bindings? And if so, how can I remove one of the port bindings to allow myself to log in from the python script?

[Multiple Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHQPO.png)
[Trying both of the Ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukR6m.png)

**Edit**
You'll notice that the second attempt to log in brings up a username error. I've tried all of the standard ones for SQL Server, like SA, me, and root. Is there a way to find out which username I'm supposed to use?

Comment: Can we assume that you've tried `SERVER=server_ip,1433` in addition to `SERVER=server_ip,81` ...?

Comment: Yeah. I'll edit the original question.

Comment: According to the screenshots you are NOT passing to the connection string the user and the password. It should be the second try of the screenshot "trying both of the ports" but adding the user and password. Check [this external link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for info on the SQL Server connection string parameters.

Comment: Are the username and password the same ones as when I instantiated the Docker container that holds the SQL Server?

Comment: I would expect the SQL login to be `sa` and the password to be what you specified for `SA_PASSWORD` as per the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: That was the ticket! Thanks @GordThompson